# CS conference paper rejected but recommended for conjunct workshop

Tags: conference, computer-science, paper-submission, workshop

Earlier this year my paper was rejected for conference A with 3 highly rejects, so I tried to revise it and then submitted it to conference B. This time I still got rejected with 1 weak accept and 2 rejects. However the program committee has just told me that my paper can be a candidate for one of the conjunct workshops and if I agree they will forward my paper to the workshop for review.

The thing is the deadline for conference A next year has just been extended so me and my advisor are considering resubmitting the paper to it. I have already been revising the paper before conference B contacted me. My first submission to conference A got really bad (but very helpful) reviews. This time the reviews are more positive as their main concern is only about experiments and evaluation that need to be more thorough. They hardly have problems with my design, which used to have a lot of flaws pointed out by the first review. So should I try the workshop with probably higher chance to get accepted, or should I bet my 2nd chance with conference A?  By the reviews I know that my paper is getting better, but since it’s already the 2nd rejection, I am not so confident that I can make it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nobody can tell you what you *should* do.

But I can tell you what *I would* do: Agree to have the paper sent to the workshop, and then make absolutely sure that my *next* submission to Conference A doesn't suffer from the same problems.  Get this paper out the door, learn from my mistakes, and move on.  There will always be another paper.

In my experience, a unanimous "strong reject" is an *unambiguous* signal that conference A does not want your paper, and even major modifications are unlikely to rescue it.

On the other hand, [the meaning of review scores vary significantly between sub-fields of CS, and between conferences in the same sub-field, and even between iterations of the same conference](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/99593/65).  So you **really** need to ask someone that works in your specific subfield how to interpret the *narrative* content of your reviews.  In particular, **ask your advisor**.